# Осветлить фон яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, яндекс-карты

Как сделать так, чтоб "осветлить" яндекс карту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно фото осветлить, то на див фильтр css накладывай, если саму карту, то смотри api. У Яндекс карт хз, а вот у гугл  карт точно можно менять. Пример https://mapkit.io